# webpack multi-compiler can not compile 2nd entry point

Tags: webpack, build, compilation, webpack-4

we use webpack in our Visual Studio C# project to bundle the scripts and styles. These finished bundles css & js files have to be in different folders at the end. For this I wanted to use the multi-compiler from webpack.

If I run the configs separately, it works as expected, it creates a styles.css in the `Content/Styles/dist` folder and a scripts.js in the `Content/Scripts/dist` folder. As soon as I want to run both configs with the multi-compiler, the scripts.js is no longer created.

The shortened `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require('webpack-fix-style-only-entries');

const buildStyles = {
  name: 'buildStyles',
  entry: {
    styles: './Content/Styles/src/styles.scss'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Content/Styles/dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
};

const buildScripts = {
  name: 'buildScripts',
  entry: {
    scripts: './Content/Scripts/src/scripts.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Content/Scripts/dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    globalObject: 'this'
  }
};

const config = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: { presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: { name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]' }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
              mimetype: 'image/png'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: { name: 'images/[name].[ext]' }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin(),
  ]
}

module.exports = [{ ...config, ...buildStyles }, { ...config, ...buildScripts }];
```

After run `webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development` we got this:

```
> Executing task: npm run dev <
> @projectname@0.0.1 dev C:\Development\PATH
> webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development

webpack-fix-style-only-entries: removing js from style only module: styles.js
webpack-fix-style-only-entries: removing js from style only module: scripts.js
Hash: a0893d6852ba01de1de9fcbdbd61d1adcdf456cc
Version: webpack 4.44.1
Child buildStyles:
    Hash: a0893d6852ba01de1de9
    Time: 1834ms
    Built at: 2020-10-16 11:14:15
                                   Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                 fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf    102 KiB          [emitted]  
                 >MANY MORE<                XXX KiB          [emitted]  
                              styles.css    164 KiB  styles  [emitted]  styles
    Entrypoint styles = styles.css
    [./Content/Styles/src/styles.scss] 39 bytes {styles} [built]
        + 2 hidden modules
    Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!Content/Styles/src/styles.scss:
        Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
        [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./Content/Styles/src/styles.scss] 784 bytes {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
            + 30 hidden modules
Child buildScripts:
    Hash: fcbdbd61d1adcdf456cc
    Time: 2253ms
    Built at: 2020-10-16 11:14:15
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    Entrypoint scripts =
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    [./Content/Scripts/src/scripts.js] 358 bytes {scripts} [built]
    [./Content/Scripts/src/utilities/dom-observer.js] 3.72 KiB {scripts} [built]
    [./Content/Scripts/src/utilities/dom-ready.js] 662 bytes {scripts} [built]
    >MANY MORE<
    [./Content/Scripts/src/vendors/polyfill.js] 2.86 KiB {scripts} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {scripts} [built]
        + 382 hidden modules
```

The marked position with an exclamation should actually contain the following:

```
    Built at: 2020-10-16 11:14:15
    Entrypoint scripts = scripts.js
```

It looks like it no longer recognizes the scripts.js in multi compile mode. It doesn't matter if I run buildStyles first and then buildScripts, or vice versa.
What mistake am i making? I hope someone can help me with the problem.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

According to the [usage docs](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin#usage) for clean-webpack-plugin, it will always clear out the entire output directory when using the default config in webpack 4+.

> All files inside webpack's output.path directory will be removed once, but the directory itself will not be. If using webpack 4+'s default configuration, everything under <PROJECT_DIR>/dist/ will be removed. Use cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns to override this behavior.

You should be able to add the `cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns` option in your webpack config to ensure that files are only removed once. Try:

```
{
    ...,
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [],
        }),
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```